# what is the difference between popen() and system() in C

Tags: c, system, popen

I want to execute a binary within my C code. Which is better to execute with? `popen()` or `system()`

**EDIT**: I tried to use `system`, but the process executing seems to get stuck in the end and does not return to my code.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Thanks

Comment: `man popen` and `man system`?

Comment: Have you tried using the popen()? or its the problem with you binary? You last edit is bit confusing

Comment: To use `popen` instead of `system` doesn't help with your actual problem: the process getting stuck.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`popen()` gives you control over the process's input or output file streams. `system()` doesn't. If you don't need to access the process's I/O, you can use `system()` for simplicity.

`system()` is in C89 and C99; `popen()` is Posix only (though the Windows API also has one).

Both functions invoke some form of a *shell* to execute the command (e.g. `/bin/sh` on Linux, and probably `cmd.exe` on Windows). If you want to execute an executable file directly and you are on Posix, you can also look at the `exec*`-family of functions in conjuction with `fork()` (since `exec()` *replaces* the current process).

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt: Neither did I until five minutes ago, when I followed Joachim's advice :-)

Comment: Important note about `popen`: It give you control over the input **OR** output stream, not both.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Sure. Maybe I should have written "xor"? English and C are different, alas.

Comment: If I close the pipe fd with `pclose`, does `pclose` return the exit value of the command I fired with `popen`?

Comment: @Strubbl: According to `man pclose` it would seem so, though you should check carefully what happens when the process exits with a signal.

Comment: A recent test revealed that I get the exit code of the command multipled by 256 as a return value from pclose, e.g. for exit code 43 I get the value 11008. Why that? But at least I get my exit code.

Comment: @Strubbl: It'll be the same semantics as for `wait`, i.e you have to use those macros to figure out whether the process returned normally or via signal, and then the return value is shifted.

Answer (score 5):

Use `popen` if you want to run a shell command and want the parent process to be able to talk to the child.  (It hooks the child's input or output up to the stream you get back.)  Otherwise, prefer the `exec` family of functions (likely in conjunction with `fork`); `exec`'d processes inherit most open file descriptors (including stdin, stdout, and stderr), so you can hook input *and* output up to whatever you like...plus, there are fewer security implications.

`system` is generally best avoided unless you have to run shell commands.  It spawns a shell to run the command, and the shell can parse the command any way it likes.  In particular, certain environment variables (like `$IFS` and/or `$PATH`) can be modified in such a way as to cause the parent to execute programs you never intended it to.  Although `popen` appears to do the same thing, it at least provides functionality that makes it worthwhile in the general case.

Comment: You can only do *either* input *or* output, I believe. `popen()` also spawns a shell.