# popen vs system function in C

Tags: c, unix

Is The benefit of using popen is only to read the ouput produced by a command or there are some more benefits or advantages of popen over system.

Consider two programs below:

Program 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *more,*who;

    if (!(more = popen("more", "w")))
    {
            printf("Command `more` not found!");
            return -1;
    }
    if (!(who = popen("who", "r")))
    {
            printf("Command `who` not found!");
            return -1;
    }

    while (!feof(who))
    {
            char buffer[100];
            if (fgets(buffer, 100, who) != NULL)
            {
                    fputs(buffer, more);
            }
    }

    fclose(more);
    fclose(who);
  return 0;
 }
```

Program 2:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    system("who|more");
    return 0;
}
```

Why should i use **Program1** if i can do the same thing in one line as done in **Program2**.

Comment: If you did a little research, you would have come across [this Stack Overflow thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538324/what-is-the-difference-between-popen-and-system-in-c).

Comment: Note that you should use pclose() on file descriptors you opened with popen().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two programs you have provided as examples are not equivalent.  `popen` gives you a pair of file handles you can use to read and write input and output to and from stdin/stdout of the running process in an interactive manner.  The `system` call is merely executing that and redirecting stdin of the current process to that of the invoked child process, and stdout of that process to stdout of the current (host) process.

It depends what you are trying to achieve, in general.  If your goal is simply to run a command, `system` works fine.  If you're interested in reading its output in a programmatic manner and processing it (and possibly generating more input), then `popen` is going to work better.

Comment: From the popen(3) documentation: `Since a pipe is by definition unidirectional, the type argument may specify only reading or writing, not both` -- you read on one side and you write on the other. Within one program you cannot read and write on the pipe. It is unidirectional by definition. You've got to use pipe(2) to achieve that feat.